# Need Excel Macro to Realize Blank Space should Be "00" for Hour (Time)

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am importing data from a text file and using a macro to format in Excel.  It recognizes and formats time (hh:mm:ss) - except when it's e.g. 00:15:27 - the data drops the 0's for hh completely and my macro then recognizes the mm:ss as hh:mm. I track data for 24 hours - so when it's midnight I lose the hour in the data and might have a funky hour of 53:02:00 for example, or I could have 10:43:00 - thinking it's 10 o'clock and not 00:10:43.

Any way to get the macro to recognize there should be something there and change it to OO?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the macro look like?

Comment: Is the process of Importing text file part of the macro or is it separate from the macro processing? If separate, you may also want to check how the import is happening and if anything can be debugged at that level before coming to macro.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have **text** values in **A1** through **A10** like:

[image]

and we want all the 5-character data to be treated like they have *00:* in front of them.  We can test for length:

```
Sub MakeTime()
    Dim r As Range, v As String
    For Each r In Range("A1:A10")
        v = r.Text
        If Len(v) = 5 Then v = "00:" & v
        r.Value = TimeValue(v)
    Next r
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]